# Why doesn't MyModel.all.each{|m| m.destroy} work as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to clear a table in my railsapp , without dropping the database and migrating...

```
 MyModel.all.each{|m| m.destroy}
```

I would expect this code to delete every record in the my_model table, but this is not happening...
using Rails 2.3.4 + MySQL 5.1

EDIT:
the issue was based on the plugin better_nested_set which didn't allow me to delete the entries in that order

`MyModel.delete_all` worked on the other hand , maybe because it executes truncate on the database (?)

Comment: I know of no reason at all why that wouldn't work. I just tested it with some data I had in a table and it worked perfectly fine. What John Topley said is correct, that's a better way to do it, but yours should have worked as well. I think I would break it down and make sure each step works. That is, does "MyModel.all" return what you expect. And does "MyModel.all.each { | m | <print something out about each item> }" work? Then can you do a "list = MyModel.all" and "list[0].destroy" work?

Comment: John is right and if you look at the source for `destroy_all` then it does pretty much what is shown here anyway: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002274

Comment: I turned out I had some dependencies within the database, and the deletion didn't cascaded right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `MyModel.destroy_all` to delete all the records for your model.

Comment: the only caveat is that if you're doing anything with callbacks (before_destroy, after_destroy, etc.) this will bypass them.  Otherwise it will do what you want and do so much more quickly than calling destroy on each instance.

Comment: That is totally wrong, semanticart! It's the `delete_all` method that bypasses the callbacks.